# jquery post on document ready

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

All i want is, a data will pass into this php file: check.php and this php file will pass data into that function when the page is ready. this is just an expirement.

ok I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("check.php", {
        name: "log"
    }, function(data) {
        if (data === "yes") {
            alert('has been login');
        } else {
            alert('has not login');
        }
    });
});​
```

and i have this php code ("check.php") where the jquery post will pass the data into.
​

```
<? //check
$chk = $_POST['name'];

if (isset($chk === "log")) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) {
        if ($_COOKIE['admin'] === "login") {
            echo "yes";
        }
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
} else {
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

but nothing happen, even i change the whole code in check.php into: "echo "yes";" theres nothing happen,  i guess, its either there is no data receive or there is no data pass. Hope someone could help me into this simple and cute problem that im stuck with. thank you in advance

Comment: do you have jQuery loaded in your page ? Are you seeing any script errors in fierbug console ?

Comment: Noting that this is just an experiment, but this is code is not ideal for a production environment. Cookies can be set/manipulated by the user. Anyone could set a cookie called `admin`=`login` and access your pages without even entering a username and password. Yes, the possibility of this happening is low, but a simple way to overcome this would be to use $_SESSION instead of cookies.

Comment: @ Shyju: yes of course I have jquery loaded.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: a link what??

Comment: @AndrewR: im poor in using sessions, i mean im not good at it, basically i dont know how to make it. :(

Comment: Instead of `isset($chk === "log")`, use `isset($chk) and $chk === "log"`. This seems not to be your problem right now, but it will be :) Try without the echo even, just a static page with "yes" in it... just to be fixed if the problem is from php or client side

Comment: the only problem here, is I guess there is no data that has been pass to check.php and receive to a jquery success function. In general, i think there is a problem in post function, but i just cant figured it out. can someone here can make it a say? mmm.

Comment: @user1292042 At the top of your pages, add `session_start();`, then just set it like `$_SESSION[admin'] = 'login';` This link will give you a basic lesson on PHP Sessions: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: Use Firebug, see if there are errors then, it seems PHP has nothing to do with it all. Check for syntax errors, and put `alert`s everywhere, so that you know where you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed a closing brace. This just works as expected:

```
 $.post('check.php', { name: 'log' }, function(data) { 
     if (data === "yes") 
      { 
         alert ('has been login'); 
       } 
       else 
     { 
     alert ('has not login'); 
     } 
  });
```

Run this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S53k5/ 
 and you will see the call passing by in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's because you're using the header "name" and that is a reserved keyword.